# remove "\n" from values fields results in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can I remove "\n" from results of searching values in mongo db without remove it from the values of mongo db ?
please I need your help!

Comment: $trim https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trim/

Comment: thank you sam for your help but this function remove "\n" just from the begenning and my values contains "\n" in the middele :( :( can you help me more please !!

Comment: After getting a result you can manipulate it with regex to remove '\n'

Comment: thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example with 2 documents:

```
db.testcol.insert({
    textstr: "Hello World\nBye World\nHello World\n"
})
db.testcol.insert({
    textstr: "Testing\n123\nTesting\n"
})

db.testcol.find({}, {_id: 0, textstr: 1}).forEach(function(e, i) {
    e.textstr=e.textstr.replace(new RegExp('\n', 'g'), "");
    printjson(e);
});
```

Will output:

```
{
    "textstr" : "Hello WorldBye WorldHello World"
}
{
    "textstr" : "Testing123Testing"
}
```

Worth noting that if you want to replace the /n with another character, such as a space, you can do that by changing the second parameter of replace to a string of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "textstr": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": { "$split": ["$textstr", "\n"] },
        "initialValue": "",
        "in": { "$concat": ["$$this", " ", "$$value"] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: thank you Anthony, but when I try it I receive a message that  indiquate "reduce" is invalide operator :( !!any suggestations please ??

Comment: What is your mongodb version?

Comment: how can i konw the version I use Robomongo 1.0 R-C1 !! I check mongo --version but I had no results !!

Comment: Run `db.version()`

Comment: I had as a result 3.2.5 !!

Comment: You have to upgrade to 3.4 or above to use `$reduce`

Comment: Thank you a lot Mr.Anthony ,I will try to do it.