# what query can be used to replace \n with space for the text all documents in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have many documents that have \n, and I want to replace them with white space. Can anyone help me to do that in MongoDB?

{"Definition": "The \n sequence is a popular one found in many languages that support escape sequences."}

I want it to be like this:

{"Definition": "The  sequence is a popular one found in many languages that support escape sequences."}

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove "\n" from values fields results in mongo db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52427002/remove-n-from-values-fields-results-in-mongo-db)